# How to correctly "undercore" with two uppercase letters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

In javascript, I have this simple string: `justAQuestion`
I'd like to transform it to `just_a_question`.
Using [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string), [Ember.String](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html) I have the same bad result:
`just_aquestion`.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Here's a JSBin to reproduce the problem: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tudepeceli/edit?html,js,output

Comment: What would be the preferred behavior if your string starts with a capital?

Comment: JustAQuestion -> just_a_question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `AQ` is treated as a single 'word'. If you always want to replace a capital letter with underscore and its lowercased version, use something like this:

```
var replacement = source.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(m) {
  return '_' + m.toLowerCase();
});
```

... or just...

```
source.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '_$1').toLowerCase();
```

It gets a bit tricky when you have to dasherize strings starting with capital letter. One possible case is just replace all the prefix '_' with...

```
source.replace(/^_+/, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like so:

```
var s = "justAQuestion";
var n = s.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "_$1").toLowerCase();
```

Yields: `just_a_question`.

The above assumes that you do not have words such as `ThisIsJustAQuestion` (that is, upper case at the beginning).

Comment: to strip `-`  from beginning of string you could use `^-+`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function transferString(str){
  
  newStr = "";
  for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
     if(str[i] == str[i].toUpperCase()){
       newStr += "_" +  str[i].toLowerCase() + "_";
     }else{
       newStr += str[i];
    }
  }
  return newStr;
}

alert(transferString("justAQuestion"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create own method, [Here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/quyecapave/edit?html,js,output) is working code.

```
String.prototype.allUnderscore=function(str){
  return this.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '_$1').toLowerCase();
}
```